# limit superior and inferior of a sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading a book about measure theory by J. Elstrodt.
In the book the limit superior is defined as (translated into English):
$\underset {n\rightarrow\infty}\varlimsup A_n:= \{x\in X: x\in A_n \text { for an infinite number of } n \in \mathbb{N}\} $
And the limit inferior as:
$\underset {n\rightarrow\infty}\varliminf A_n:= \{x\in X: \text { An } n_0(x) \in \mathbb{N} \text { exists so that } x \in A_n \text { for all } n  \ge n_0(x)\} $

I don't know how to get from these definitions to the following equations:
$\underset {n\rightarrow\infty}\varlimsup A_n = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_k  $;
$\underset {n\rightarrow\infty}\varliminf A_n = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_k  $

Is there an easy example to understand this and to see the difference between both limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the following statements are equivalent:

- $a\notin\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$
- some $n$ exists with $a\notin\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$
- some $n$ exists with $a\notin A_k$ for every $k\geq n$.
- the set $\{k\mid x\in A_k\}$ is finite.
- $a\notin\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$

Looking at first and last bullet we conclude that: $$\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$

---

Observe that the following statements are equivalent:

- $a\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$
- some $n$ exists with $a\in\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$
- some $n$ exists with $a\in A_k$ for every $k\geq n$
- $a\in\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$

Looking at first and last bullet we conclude that: $$\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$

---

Example:

Let $A_n=\mathbb R$ if $n$ is odd and $A_n=(n,\infty)$ otherwise.

Then:

- $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=\mathbb R$
- $\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=\varnothing$

Also observe that evidently always: $$\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n\subseteq\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$$

In the special case of equality we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists, and this with: $$\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$$

Comment: This is a great answer. It fitted my level of knowledge and provided an easy to understand example.

Comment: You are very welcome.